# DKIM & SPF records should be on the sender email domain or on the smtp domain?

Tags: postfix, spf, dkim

I have two(2) vps servers. One of them hosts my website and the other has Postfix installed on it.

```
VPS[1]: websitedomain.com
VPS[2]: postfixdomain.com
```

I am using `smtp.postfixdomain.com` to send an email from `contact@websitedomain.com`. On which domain should i have `DKIM` and `SPF` records?

Should i have them on `websitedomain.com` on `postfixdomain.com` or on `smtp.postfixdomain.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spam filters will query the domain of the email sender.

If you're sending from contact@websitedomain.com, then SPF+DKIM+DMARC records should be configured for websitedomain.com.

Comment: And there's no record needed for the smtp.postfixdomain.com?

Comment: At least it's not directly relevant to the mail being sent from websitedomain.com. Postfixdomain.com (or its associated IP addresses) may have other problems that makes it look less than trustworthy, and that can affect the deliverability of mail sent through it, but when it comes to the header content of mail from websitedomain.com, it's the DNS TXT records for websitedomain.com that are relevant.

Comment: Ok, thank you! May i ask what are those problems that might make the smtp server look less trustworthy?

Comment: It being a known spam sender or an open relay, which today pretty much amounts to the same thing. Specific IP ranges may have a less than stellar reputation among spam filters. Usually correct and aggressively configured SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records increase the trustworthiness of mail sent from a domain enough to counter such effects, but to give a concrete example I once had huge trouble getting Yahoo to accept mail from a specific server without routing that domain’s mail through a larger operator.

Comment: Oky then I hope my droplets are not in any of those ip ranges :-s. Thank you for helping me!